# Jquery Looping through on mouseovers, with muliple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops

Well, hopefully I can articulate this and get my point across. I've done some searches, but nothing really hits it.

The JSfiddle page: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsNbZ/5/) Also, some of the CSS isn't going to be sized correct since that's not the right image.

But here's the Javascript code:

```
 //mouse over
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){
    $("#client"+i).on("mouseover", function(){
        $(this).removeClass("clientsOff").addClass("clientsOn");
        for(var e = 0; e < 10; e++){
            (function(){
                $("#overlayC"+e).css({'display':'block'});
                })();
            };
        });
    };

  //mouse leave 
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){
    $("#client"+i).on("mouseleave", function(){
        $(this).removeClass("clientsOn").addClass("clientsOff");
        (function(){
            for(var e = 0; e<10; e++){
                $("#overlayC"+e).css({'display':'none'})
            }})();
        });
    };
```

Ok, to the point. There are two hover activities going on here. One of them (that is working correctly) is just switching classes, with each hover, and doing them one at a time.

Now, the second is another hover effect, but instead of doing it one at a time all of them show up.

Now the simplest way to fix this is to just a hover for each id, but that will take forever/not very inefficient. Thus why I'm using a loop here. Now, I know it needs to have another closure, but it's not working correctly.

I've tried a few different ways of doing this, but either they throw the same result or just don't work at all.

And yes the starting loop could all be one, but for now it helps keep things separated so I can read things better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are displaying all `overlayC`s on each mouse over

```
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){
    (function(i){
        $("#client"+i).hover(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("clientsOff").addClass("clientsOn");
            $("#overlayC"+i).css({'display':'block'});
        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass("clientsOn").addClass("clientsOff");
            $("#overlayC"+i).css({'display':'none'})
        });
    })(i);
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DtzhV/)

Comment: Thanks, I see what I did. I tried something like this but it was missing a few thing. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's you [jsFiddle edited](http://jsfiddle.net/wsNbZ/10/)

```
$('[id*="client"]').each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("clientsOff").addClass("clientsOn")
        .find('[id*="overlayC"]').eq(0).css({display:'block'});
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass("clientsOn").addClass("clientsOff")
        .find('[id*="overlayC"]').eq(0).css({display:'none'});
    })
});
```

if your code is in the head do a $(function(){//code});

Comment: for some reason your overlayC called all but was able to control with eq(0)

Comment: It does do, what needs to be done, but this one would move the whole client div (#clientRail), and changes the positioning on the last one, slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS still looks creepy, but however, in order to stop the entire parenting tree's mouseover events to fire, edit line 3 and 4 like below:

```
... function(elem){
        if (elem.target!=this) {return false;} 
...
```